# web.config file locked during Azure App Service Deploy task

Tags: azure, azure-devops, continuous-deployment

We configured a automatic release pipeline in VSTS to publish to azure. When running the Azure App Service Deploy (v3) task it results in an error (since this morning: 2017-09-11).

We tried checking the options:

- Take App Offline
- Rename locked files (same as MSDEPLOY_RENAME_FILES_FLAG = 1 in appsetting in azure slot)

We also checked/set the following options:

- Publish using Web Deploy
- set the correct (did not change and checked) path to setparameters.xml
- Remove additional files at destination
- Exclude files from the App_Data folder

We also use Stackify for monitoring the page. This also did not change since the last working release (or actual multiple releases). No other extensions are installed.

The file locked is the web.config file, but this should not be locked by either Azure app services (asume IIS) or Stackify.

We were originally running v2 of the App Service deploy task, and updated due to this error.

Please advise how to continue resolving this error.

Comment: Why I didn't think of it before: Just restart the app (slot) in azure and retry. This does work at least for now to publish. I'll call again when problem returns.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't happen again after restart. Probably a glitch.