# Azure Devops : How to enable the Rename locked files (RenameFilesFlag) with an "IIS web app deploy" task

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, locked-files

I'm having a problem with a locked DLL file while I tried to deploy with a Release Pipeline in Azure Devops.

The screenshot of the error is:

[image]

Output as text:

```
2021-03-31T17:43:18.2626492Z ##[error]Error Code: ERROR_FILE_IN_USE
More Information: Web Deploy cannot modify the file 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.x64.dll' on the destination because it is locked by an external process.  In order to allow the publish operation to succeed, you may need to either restart your application to release the lock, or use the AppOffline rule handler for .Net applications on your next publish attempt.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_FILE_IN_USE.
    Error count: 1.
```

It seems the problem is caused by a wrongly disposed .NET resource. (ex: unmanaged SqlConnection)
Anyway, I can't change the source code.

Here is my Release Pipeline.

[image: Azure Devops Release Deploy]

Here are my questions:

Q1) I'm trying to use the "-RenameFilesFlag" (MSDEPLOY_RENAME_LOCKED_FILES) as described here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-rm-web-app-deployment?view=azure-devops

[web.config file locked during Azure App Service Deploy task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46154594/web-config-file-locked-during-azure-app-service-deploy-task)

How do I have to specify this argument ?
Do I have to fill the "Additional arguments" textbox ? I tried different values and I always get an
"Unrecognized argument" error.

Q2) If the "-RenameFilesFlag" is not available for this task.
Can I use the "Take App Offline" to unlock a file ?

Q3) On another post on StackOverflow, I saw a checkbox option specific to "Rename locked files"
[Getting ERROR_FILE_IN_USE while using Web Deploy in Azure App Service Task v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52503666/getting-error-file-in-use-while-using-web-deploy-in-azure-app-service-task-v3)

I don`t have this option in my task. Is it possible that I am confusing two type of Deploy tasks ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> MSDEPLOY_RENAME_LOCKED_FILES

As far as I know, this method only supports Azure Web APP service. This option is used to set the Azure App settings(cloud).  It does not apply to IIS deployment(on-prem).

> ##[error]Error Code: ERROR_FILE_IN_USE

To solve this issue, you could try the following methods:

1.You could set the `Take App Offline` option in IIS Web Deploy task.

[image]

Here is a doc about [Taking an Application Offline before Publishing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/publish/deploying-application-packages/taking-an-application-offline-before-publishing)

2.You could Stop your website before deploying the app and restart it after deployment.

You could add `IIS web app manage task` to stop and start the IIS Website.

For example:

[image]

**Update1:**

As ssinfod's comment: stop the application pool could solve this issue.

We can also achieve this in `IIS web app manage task`

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I tried both solutions but it did not release the lock on the DLL file. It seems I also have to stop the application pool. In particular, the "Rename locked files" option seems much needed.

Comment: Do you know if the missing options available in "Azure Web APP service" will be available in the "IIS deployment(on-prem)" (ie: "IIS web app deploy" task) ?

Comment: Hi @ssinfod. Thanks for your update. I could understand your requirement. But I am afraid that there is no such option / argument in IIS web deploy task. This "Rename locked files" option is used to set the app setting variable(MSDEPLOY_RENAME_LOCKED_FILES ) in azure web app. IIS website doesn't have this setting. So it doesn't supportted by IIS web app deploy task.

Comment: For now, I solved my problem by stopping the application pool with an Azure "IIS Web app Manage" task. It's not ideal but it will do the work. I will also watch the following issue https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/354 which seems to be exactly my problem. Ideally, the fix should to be made in the .Net Core SqlClient. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks. Take App Offline works for me